# Aligning Events against right Time in Week and Day Mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-2

I am using Full Calendar. When i have multiple Events in a Day. The alignment of the Events in Day/Week mode is incorrect. Any idea how to auto increase and align the timing correctly based on the events?

**Version: 2.3**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see you've used some custom CSS. Firstly remove that custom theme in case its rules are placing elements incorrectly, and re-test. Also check you haven't got some code which is changing the event descriptions to display an incorrect time. Without seeing your code it's hard to say what's gone wrong. I note also you've mentioned fullCalendar 2.3. Is it worth upgrading to the latest version to see if that helps? Some bugs may have been fixed, although I don't think it ever had a bug this bad, which suggests it's your code at fault, not the calendar (hence why we need to see it).

Comment: @ADyson Will test it out and get back to you. Will remove the Theme files and test as well once. This came in the theme. So need to check if i can upload to the latest version easily.